# Switch between two search sources(modes)

Tags: android, search, user-research

Android guidelines provide good information on search design https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/search.html but I need something beyond that.

User should have an ability to quickly switch between two search modes - lets say, it's switch between english and hispanic dictionaries.
One of the obvious ways is to show Eng-His switch when SearchView is focused, but it does not look good, especially with new Material design.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine it like this :)

Material design style....

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgzY7d.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: that's the one we've implemented at the end ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why not search **BOTH** dictionaries once the user submits the search?

Then work out for yourself which dictionary the search words are part of and search on that basis.

That way you don't need a switch and can provide results based on whatever route the user takes. It would not be too difficult to see which words show up in which dictionary and make an informed decision based on that.

I think you will probably find people might do an initial search without switching the dictionary, then make the switch after realising nothing came back initially and try again.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of search engine would you be using?

Search engines such as Google should be able to pick up which language you are searching in. The user shouldn't change language, however they might on their keyboard and for their auto-spelling check.

Maybe something like this?

The language switch is not as important as the search results and therefore could be put lower down the page.

[image: Altered image from dimshik]

(image altered from @dimshik)